# Access Camel exchange property in XML DSL

Tags: apache-camel

Assuming I have set a Camel exchange **property** in a Processor ...Example

```
exchange.setProperty(LASTPROCESSED, sortedBody[0].attribute6)
```

What would be the proper way of referencing this property in my ***XML based route*** ?

I tried ${property:LASTPROCESSED} and ${exchangeProperty:LASTPROCESSED}

I have no trouble referencing exchange Headers ( *i.e. ${headers.xxx}* )

Yes ...I have trolled through countless answers here without finding a solution.

I am running Camel 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an issue elsewhere in the Route ...the proper way to access appears to be ${exchangeProperty.xxx}